# VS2019 (16.8.1), C#, XML Comments, Intellisense not showing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, xml-comments

I have a Xamarin Forms project (C#) that I am working on in VS2019 (16.8.1) and I have noticed that if I add XML comments to the properties of classes within the project they are not then showing up when I hover over that property in another class where it is used.

Not working:

```
/// <summary>
/// Property1 && Property2 && Property3 && Property4
/// </summary>
public Boolean IsTypeA
{
    get {
        return Property1 && Property2 && Property3 && Property4;
    }
}
```

This never used to be the case; any ideas what may have changed that I have missed in order to restore this functionality?

Comment: I have just tried creating a new solution and projects for Xamarin Forms and in this new project the comments show correctly. I must therefore assume this this has something to do with the project originally being carried forward through previous versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: As far as I can see, all of the project properties are the same (bar assembly name etc.) between the projects affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the comments I had added were *invalid XML*.

I was trying to show the meaning of some read-only helper properties by simply showing the code that was used to evaluate the result - this included ampersand characters...

Fixed version of comment:

```
/// <summary>
/// Property1 &amp;&amp; Property2 &amp;&amp; Property3 &amp;&amp; Property4
/// </summary>
public Boolean IsTypeA
{
    get {
        return Property1 && Property2 && Property3 && Property4;
    }
}
```

M.

Comment: Thanks, I had a very similar issue with < and > in the comment and this answer made me realize that right away.